# How can I extend CloudBuild timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have tried many different options for extending CloudBuild duration but my gcloud app deploy step will always times out after 10 mins. Following tips from other threads, I have tried this setting on my local terminal

```
gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 2000
```

I have also tried many combinations of build job and task level timeouts, but the step always fails at 10 minutes with this error in the cloud build logs

```
ERROR: context deadline exceeded
```

And this error on my laptop

```
Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Cloud build did not succeed within 10m.
```

My cloudbuild.yaml is

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  args: [ install ]

- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ng'
  args: ['build', '--prod']

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  #entrypoint: 'bash'
  #args: ['-c', 'gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 2000 && gcloud app deploy']
  args: [ app, deploy ]
  timeout: 2000s

timeout: 4600s
```

And I run the build from my laptop with the command

```
gcloud builds submit . --config=cloudbuild.yaml --timeout=1h
```

How can I allow the gcloud app deploy step to run for longer than 10 mins?

## Update 1

I have also tried various versions of this as per comments below, still the same error message

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  args: [ install ]
  timeout: 2000s

- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ng'
  args: ['build', '--prod']
  timeout: 2000s

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: [ app, deploy ]
  timeout: 2000s

timeout: 6100s
```

I don't know if it is relevant or not, but looking at the logs, it appears the gcloud app deploy step is compiling the code again, same as the previous step.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't!

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I moved some of the build to my local machine to work around it

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine#configuring_the_deployment):

> Add a timeout field to the build step. This is because Cloud Build build steps and builds have a default timeout of 10 minutes and App Engine deployments could take longer than that to complete. Specifying a longer timeout will make sure that the build doesn't timeout if gcloud app deploy takes longer than 10 minutes to complete.

Example:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy']
  timeout: '1600s'
```

The above example will add a 27-minute timeout to your App Engine deployment.

Comment: Weird about the quotes. The [How-to](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout_2) doesn't use them for that field.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it. Turns out that with or without single quotes the final result should remain the same. Just to be clear, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout_2) that you referenced is to set up a `timeout` for the _entire_ build and not for a _specific_ `step` of the build as I suggested in my answer. Did try the above example? Did you get it to work?

Comment: I'm not the asker. However, note that the asker is using `timeout` (though without quotes) and shows it in their example.

Comment: Yes, you are correct and the OP shows that the error occurs at step 2, which is the App Engine deployment step. Since the OP is using a more granular `timeout` (timeout: 4600s) for the entire build and has other build steps, I would suggest to add the proper step timeout and execute the App Engine deployment step firstly to discard any issues with it. I also noticed that the OP's first build step is `npm install` which might potentially be installing a large number of dependencies. I will wait for their answer. Feel free to edit my answer if you consider it convenient.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions, however still no luck. I've used quotes and also no quotes, also added a timeout to each step and increased the timeout for the entire build. The gcloud app deploy step times out after 10 mins

Comment: Also just want to clarify which step the error is occuring at, I am of the understanding that the steps start at zero. So step 2 is gcloud app deploy. Also the error message says 'Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Cloud build did not succeed within 10m'

Comment: Yes, you are correct, Cloud Build steps always start at 0, and the error occurs at step 2, which indicates that the timeout issue happens upon deployment, as mentioned earlier. You said that you noticed that at step 2, the code is being compiled again, same as step 1. The command `gcloud app deploy` builds an image with your source code and deploys that image on App Engine. This will generate a new build and it is likely that it might be causing timeout issues. Could you split your Cloud Build into small steps? Are you using App Engine standard or flexible? How long do steps 0 & 1 take?

Comment: I had to do `1600s` with an `s`